# How to debug Google Code Jam interactive problems on VSCode using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I tried downloading the example interactive problem [number guessing problem](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000000130/0000000000000523). They offer a `local testing tool` in the Description tab, a python solution in the Analysis tab, a [interactive_runner.py](https://storage.googleapis.com/coding-competitions.appspot.com/interactive_runner.py) that runs both scripts simultaneously.

After saving the solution in a `solution.py`, I can run this on shell successfully with: `python3 interactive_runner.py python3 local_testing_tool.py 0 -- python3 solution.py`.

The problem is I can't debug it using VSCode. I tried putting all 3 files in one folder and using the following launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Arquivo Atual",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "interactive_runner.py python3 local_testing_tool.py 0 -- python3 ${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run solutions.py with the debugger I get the error:

```
env DEBUGPY_LAUNCHER_PORT=40453 /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/bin/python3.8 /home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.74986/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/launcher "interactive_runner.py python3 local_testing_tool.py 0 -- python3 /home/user/workspace/wargames/GoogleCodeJam/2018/PracticeSession/NumberGuessing/solution.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.74986/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.74986/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.74986/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 262, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 232, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(fname) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'interactive_runner.py python3 local_testing_tool.py 0 -- python3 /home/user/workspace/wargames/GoogleCodeJam/2018/PracticeSession/NumberGuessing/solution.py'
```

Any better approach on how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to specify `python3` twice? If `interactive_runner.py` is running Python for you it might prevent the debugger from working.

Comment: @BrettCannon `interactive_runner.py` run two programs (in this case in python): `python3 local_testing_tool.py 0` and also `python3 solution.py`. It passes the output of one program as input to the other. That is why there is two `python3`, in fact they are 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"program"` argument expects only the path to a file, hence the error about there being "no such file or directory". What you want to do is take the rest of your execution line and make them arguments:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Arquivo Atual",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "interactive_runner.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["python3", "local_testing_tool.py", "0", "--", "python3", "${file}"]  // Not sure if `${file}` will work here.
        }
    ]
}
```